# Convert C# lambda expression to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have three statments in C# and have problems to convert them to vb.net, can anyone show howw this has to be done in vb.net?:

```
_hubConnection.Reconnecting += () =>
{
    if (_hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Reconnecting)
    {
        CanSend = false;
        Status = "Connection reconnecting...";
    }
};

_hubConnection.Closed += async () =>
{
    if (_hubConnection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
    {
        CanSend = false;
        Status = "Connection lost, reconnecting in a bit...";
        await Task.Delay(_reconnectDelay);
        await Connect();
    }
};

_hubConnection.Error += ex =>
{
    LogMessages.Add(ex.ToString());
};
```

What i did so far (please confirm whether its ok, and last one i have no idea:

```vb
AddHandler _hubConnection.Reconnecting, Sub()
    If _hubConnection.State = ConnectionState.Connected Then
      CanSend = false;
      Status = "Connection reconnecting..."                                                                                                             End Sub)
     End If
End Sub
```

The second one:

```vb
AddHandler _hubConnection.Closed, Async Sub()
            If _hubConnection.State = ConnectionState.Disconnected Then
                CanSend = false;
                Status = "Connection lost, reconnecting in a bit...";
                await Task.Delay(_reconnectDelay);
                await Connect();
             End If
             End Sub
```

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION:**

```
 Private thisLock As New Object

    Private Const _hubUrl As String = "http://localhost:4848"
    Private _hubConnection As HubConnection
    Private _hubProxy As IHubProxy

    Private _connectionStateLocker As New Object()
    Private _canSend As Boolean
    Private _status As String





    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Await Connect()
        Catch ex As Exception
            SyncLock thisLock
                msg_listview.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With {.BackColors = New Color() {Color.Red}, .TextColor = Color.White, .Text = "Form1_Load: " + ex.ToString()})
            End SyncLock
        End Try
    End Sub

    Async Function Connect() As Task

        SyncLock _connectionStateLocker

            'this is protect against connecting for only once..
            If _hubConnection IsNot Nothing AndAlso _hubConnection.State <> ConnectionState.Disconnected Then
                Return
            End If

            _hubConnection = New HubConnection(_hubUrl)
            AddHandler _hubConnection.Reconnecting, Sub()
                                                        If _hubConnection.State = ConnectionState.Connected Then
                                                            _canSend = False
                                                            msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                                    msg_listview.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With {.BackColors = New Color() {Color.Black}, .TextColor = Color.White, .Text = "Connection reconnecting"})
                                                                                End Sub)
                                                        End If
                                                    End Sub

            AddHandler _hubConnection.StateChanged, Sub(e)
                                                        If e.OldState = ConnectionState.Reconnecting AndAlso e.NewState = ConnectionState.Connected Then
                                                            msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                                    msg_listview.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With {.BackColors = New Color() {Color.Black}, .TextColor = Color.White, .Text = String.Format("Connected to {0} via {1}", _hubUrl, _hubConnection.Transport.Name)})
                                                                                End Sub)
                                                            _canSend = True
                                                        End If
                                                    End Sub

            AddHandler _hubConnection.Closed, Async Sub()
                                                  _canSend = False
                                                  msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                          msg_listview.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With {.BackColors = New Color() {Color.Black}, .TextColor = Color.White, .Text = "Connection lost, reconnecting in a bit..."})
                                                                      End Sub)
                                                  _canSend = True
                                                  Await Task.Delay(3000)
                                                  Await Connect()
                                              End Sub

            AddHandler _hubConnection.Error, Sub(ex)
                                                 msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                         msg_listview.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With {.BackColors = New Color() {Color.Black}, .TextColor = Color.White, .Text = "ERROR:" + ex.ToString})
                                                                     End Sub)
                                             End Sub

            _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Main")



            _hubProxy.[On](Of String)("heartbeat", (Sub()

                                                        msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                                msg_listview.Items.Add("Recieved hearbeat")
                                                                            End Sub)

                                                    End Sub))

            _hubProxy.[On](Of HelloModel)("sendHelloObject", Sub(hello)

                                                                 msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                                         msg_listview.Items.Add("Recieved sendHelloObject: Molly: " + hello.Molly + " Age: " + hello.Age.ToString())
                                                                                     End Sub)

                                                             End Sub)


            msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                    msg_listview.Items.Add("Connecting...")
                                End Sub)

        End SyncLock


        'Keep trying to connect until it works (dont just call Start expect to work as one time server could not be available)
        'so what we gonna to do is retry the loop over and over again until such time it works.
        While True
            Try


                Await _hubConnection.Start
                msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                        msg_listview.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                msg_listview.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With {.BackColors = New Color() {Color.Black}, .TextColor = Color.White, .Text = String.Format("Connected to {0} via {1}", _hubUrl, _hubConnection.Transport.Name)})
                                                            End Sub)
                                    End Sub)
                _canSend = True
                Exit While

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End While

    End Function
```

Comment: don't put multiple question in one topic ; open a new question (with a link to this one for context if needed) with proper title ; it'll help future readers when searching similar problems

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

```vb
    AddHandler _hubConnection.Reconnecting, Sub()
        If _hubConnection.State = ConnectionState.Reconnecting Then
            CanSend = False
            Status = "Connection reconnecting..."
        End If
    End Sub

    AddHandler _hubConnection.Reconnected, Sub()
        If _hubConnection.State = ConnectionState.Connected Then
            Status = String.Format("Connected to {0} via {1}", _hubUrl, _hubConnection.Transport.Name)
            CanSend = True
        End If
    End Sub

    AddHandler _hubConnection.Closed, Async Sub()
        If _hubConnection.State = ConnectionState.Disconnected Then
            CanSend = False
            Status = "Connection lost, reconnecting in a bit..."
            Await Task.Delay(_reconnectDelay)
            Await Connect()
        End If
    End Sub

    AddHandler _hubConnection.Error, Sub(ex)
        LogMessages.Add(ex.ToString())
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Function` lambda not returning value ; I don't think converter handle well the late stuff added to .Net

Comment: that's wrong i cannot just use += . There have to be AddHandler and then after comma ... Look at my main post for first one.

Comment: That's correct. The online converter does not seems to be aware of the handlers. See the edited post though.

Comment: one more thing - this case do i need to removehandlers if needed or in this case not?

Comment: Obviously you do not want to add the same handler over and over again. In case if these handler are going to be added only once you do not need to remove them, otherwise you would like to subscribe to them in other moment of your program. Usually this inline handler is used when you are sure that the handler will not be needed for future use.

Comment: @IvayloPetrov see my main post again please in Additional question - this is how i use it and this was based on some tutorial - Connect async function is called in form load event, but inside it can be called again if connection is lost. On my window form button click i also have reference to connect function. Does author also known about this thats why no removehandlers?

Comment: Using this method it only happens once. I would recommend using address of method. Then you can do  it when needed and remove them when you don't need them.

Comment: The Author is aware that these handlers are going to be needed only once. That's why there is no need of separate event handler methods. The downside of this approach is that you can not unsubscribe the handlers, if you want to.

Comment: ok but if loop will go rhough Connect method again those handlers wil be duplicated not? so before them should be remove handler... As it is possible they will be reached again so we would get duplication?